# Get glimpse working with web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, glimpse

I have an MVC4 project with the template Intranet Application. Glimpse is working on the MVC4 Routes but not on web api routes (the footer vanishes).
I'm thinking of creating an action in a MVCController which takes a request as parameters to instanciate the right WebApiController and calls the right action with the parameters.

Is there a better alternative ?

I tried to use this (found [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/282)) but it doesn't work :

```
<inspectors>
      <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Inspector.RoutesInspector, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
      </ignoredTypes>
    </inspectors>
</glimpse>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you mention is related to Glimpse making changes to the Routes configuration which broke the WebApi Help Pages, fortunately that issue has been solved in the meanwhile.

Based on your question, I assume that you want to see Glimpse diagnostics for WebApi related calls? Unfortunately Glimpse v1.8.4 does not support WebApi requests.

The good news is that support for WebApi is being added as we speak. You can check the [pull request](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/pull/749) to see how it's going and when it's expected to be released.

Comment: Has the support been added yet?  I am trying to debug routes with ASP.NET Web API, and the "Routes" tab doesn't have the HttpRoute names for the API, and when I make an API call (`http://<site_name>/api/mycall/10`) nothing gets registered.  Is there something specific I need to do?  Let me know if you need more explanation or it is more in depth than a quick reply comment here and I'll create a separate question.  Thanks in advance!